# I get error "Procedure or function 'stSelect' expects parameter '@stNo', which was not supplied."

Tags: c#, sql-server

The stored procedure is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[stSelect] 
    (@stNo INT) 
AS BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM stTable 
    WHERE stNo = @stNo
END
```

The C# code is:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sqlConnection1.Close();
    SqlCommand cmd;
    dataSet41.Clear();

    cmd = new SqlCommand("stSelect", sqlConnection1);
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stNo", textBox1.Text);

    sqlConnection1.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sqlDataAdapter1.SelectCommand = cmd;
    sqlDataAdapter1.Fill(dataSet41);
    sqlConnection1.Close();
}
```

Thank you very much for your help

Ali

Comment: Which line do you get the error?

Comment: maybe becasue the param is defined as int and you are supplying text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
```

since you're calling a stored procedure. Otherwise it's going to assume that "stSelect" is a SQL statement.

I'm not sure how the parameter is getting interpreted since you're adding it without specifying that it's a stored procedure.

Comment: Opening the connection gives error that connection is open. But cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure gives the correct answer. Thank you  Scott Hannen very much.

Comment: Awesome. Please don't forget to mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the value in textbox is number firstly, if yes then do the rest of the work:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int stNo;
    if (!int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out stNo))
    {
        // not a number
        return;
    }

    // It is a number so do the rest 

    sqlConnection1.Close();
    SqlCommand cmd;
    dataSet41.Clear();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("stSelect", sqlConnection1);
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stNo", stNo); //<-- number is expected
    sqlConnection1.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sqlDataAdapter1.SelectCommand = cmd;
    sqlDataAdapter1.Fill(dataSet41);
    sqlConnection1.Close();
}
```

Comment: I changed the code as you wrote but again I got that error. The problem is not string or int, the parameter is not passed to stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you must open FIRST the connection.
SOmething like:

{

```
        sqlConnection1.Open();

        Using cmd as new SqlCommand("stSelect", sqlConnection1);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stNo", textBox1.Text);
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
          sqlDataAdapter1.SelectCommand = cmd;
          sqlDataAdapter1.Fill(dataSet41);
          sqlConnection1.Close();

        End Using
                }
```

Comment: The op is opening the connection. Plus if that was the case, the error would be different.